# how to exclude "<" in regex match

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which looks like `"<name><address> and <Phone_1>"`. I have get to get the result like

```
1) <name>
2) <address>
3) <Phone_1>
```

I have tried using regex "<(.*)>" but it returns just one result.

Comment: What language...?

Comment: Hi @Andy.. it is in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you want is

```
<([^<>]+?)><([^<>]+?)> and <([^<>]+?)>
```

Which will then spit out the stuff you want in the 3 capture groups. The full code would then look something like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<([^<>]+?)><([^<>]+?)> and <([^<>]+?)>").matcher(string);

if (m.find()) {
    String name = m.group(1);
    String address = m.group(2);
    String phone = m.group(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `.*` in a regex is **greedy**. It will match as many characters as possible between the first `<` it finds and the last possible `>` it can find. In the case of your string it finds the first `<`, then looks for as much text as possible until a `>`, which it will find at the very end of the string.

You want a **non-greedy** or "lazy" pattern, which will match as few characters as possible. Simply `<(.+?)>`. The question mark is the syntax for non-greedy. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you have dynamic number of groups.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<\\w+>)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<name><address> and <Phone_1>");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```